# Remove Bootstrap line height from all H1 tags

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I run this HTML / CSS, the bottom of the letters like y and g are clipped because of the line-height CSS inherited from the Bootstrap CSS.

```css
.font2 { 
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    font-size: 12rem;
}

.gradient-text { 
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #E9D66B, #4997D0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div>
    <h1 class="font2 gradient-text">green yellow</h1>
</div>

<div>
    <h1 class="font2 gradient-text">you get this</h1>
</div>
```

I thought I could maybe use JS - e.g.

```
var cells1 = document.querySelectorAll('h1');

for (var i = 0; i < cells1.length; i++) {
  
    cell = cells1[i];
    
    // remove the line height CSS attribute?

}
```

But maybe using JS is not the best option?

I don't want to specify a line height at all on the H1 tag.

How can I remove the line-height CSS attribute from all of the H1 tags?

Comment: If you have a line height requirement - but "_don't want to specify a line height_" - how do you resolve the disparate requirement by using JavaScript?

Comment: I don't have a line height requirement though, sorry if that wasn't clear in my question. The Bootstrap CSS has a line height on it for the H1 tags, so I was looking to see if it was possible to remove it. I didn't want to e.g. put an inline style on the H1 tag to say, make it so-and-so size, I just didn't want the line-height CSS attribute on the H1 tag at all, and I thought, maybe I can remove it using JS as I can't see how to do it using CSS (e.g. like you can see a background color to transparent, I didn't know if you can override a line height to something to override an existing value).

Comment: I'll repost my answer. Let me know if it answers your question.

Comment: By the way, saying "I want to remove it" IS the requirement. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a CSS override for `line-height` of `H1`.

```
h1 {
  line-height: normal !important;
}
```

Updated the snippet also.

```css
.font2 { 
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    font-size: 12rem;
}

.gradient-text { 
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #E9D66B, #4997D0);
}

h1 {
  line-height: normal !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div>
    <h1 class="font2 gradient-text">green yellow</h1>
</div>

<div>
    <h1 class="font2 gradient-text">you get this</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then add these two rules (marked) to the `font2` class. The height of the `h1` tags will decrease significantly.

Or you can create CSS rules specifically for the `h1` tag, and put these two rules there.

```
.font2 { 
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    font-size: 12rem;

    display: inline; /*add this it*/
    line-height: 100%; /*add this it*/
}
```

```css
.font2 { 
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', cursive;
    font-size: 12rem;

    display: inline; /*add this it*/
    line-height: 100%; /*add this it*/
}

.gradient-text { 
    background-size: 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #E9D66B, #4997D0);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abril+Fatface" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div>
    <h1 class="font2 gradient-text">green yellow</h1>
</div>

<div>
    <h1 class="font2 gradient-text">you get this</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change `line-height`, but not just `line-height`, to change anything to what you want, you just need to override it the correct way, putting `!important` isn't enough, the way browser reads classes and styles is it goes from left side to right side, so basically to override an existing class all you need to do it put the override class on the right most side when defining classes or use the style tag for small changes

example:

```
<div class="existing-class override-class" style="color:red;"/>
```

this code will start with the styles of `existing-class` and then it will go forward and use the `override-class`, so anything that overlaps between those 2 classes, browser will choose the later one, meaning `override-class` will overwrite styles from `existing-class`.

Now the style tag will overwrite both the `existing-class` and `override-class`'s style and you will get color red even if you defined blue or black on either existing or override class, and thats how you can overwrite anything.